# Find the element in an array, in which left elements are smaller and right elements are larger?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures

Suppose if there's an array, find out the element left to which the elements are smaller and right to which the elements are larger. Else return -1. I know how to do this in O(n^2). But how can this be done in O(n)?

The code for O(n^2):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
int array[] = {5, 1, 4, 3, 2, 8, 10, 7, 9};
int sizeOfArray = sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]);
for (int i = 1; i < sizeOfArray-1; ++i) {
    int j = i-1;
    int k = i+1;
    while(array[j] < array[i] && array[k] > array[i]){
        if(j == 0 && k == sizeOfArray-1){
            cout << array[i];
            return 0;
        }
        if(j>0){
            j--;
        }
        if(k<sizeOfArray){
            k++;
        }

    }
}
cout << -1;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do we know anything else about the array? Is it perhaps sorted?

Comment: It's pretty trivial to do this, if you think about it. Note that there may 0, 1, or more matches (up to N, if the array is sorted).

Comment: No, it isn't sorted. It's just some array with random numbers filled in.

Comment: So, what can you do if you simply linearly scan the array?

Comment: Maybe use multiple loops separately with smart logical conditions? Also the space complexity doesn't matter.

Comment: Oh well, if you don't understand simple words, giving hints is pointless.

Comment: So you say it's impossible?

Comment: What is the programming language you suppose?

Comment: C++ would be nice.

Comment: What about additional memory? (you marked `data-structures` tag)

Comment: Memory doesn't matter. I just want some hints on the algorithm that runs on O(n) time complexity.

Comment: It is really a hint. How do you solve this problem with quadratic time?

Comment: Using two loops. First to traverse the elements in the array and the second to check whether the given condition is correct.

Comment: Just to digress for a moment, @MaxZuber nice last name man, long lost brother?

Comment: Are you able to determine in one cycle whether the first condition is valid?

Comment: Please show us some proof that you've attempted the problem - this site isn't designed to *solve* homework problems for you

Comment: @NickZuber It's not totally impossible if your grandparents were originated from Ukraine or Russia as well.

Comment: @MaxZuber I am Ukrainian!!

Comment: @NickZuber I will write you a message via LinkedIn or whatever tomorrow, stay tuned :-)

Comment: @MaxZuber The code submitted by Yves Daoust being simple works just fine. And it's O(n) as well. :/

Comment: @RaghavendraRagha It is a quite nice solution, but it fails to your own condition: "left elements are smaller and right elements are larger" for same consequent items. Check it for [1, 2, 2, 3, 4]. Items for both "2" shouldn't be in result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) scan the array from left to right, remembering the largest value so far;

2) scan the array from right to left, remembering the smallest value so far.

3) scan the two new arrays until you find a largest value not exceeding a smallest value.

Examples:

```
3 6 4 5 9 8 7

3 6 6 6 9 9 9
3 4 4 5 7 7 7
```

There is no solution.

```
3 2 4 6 9 8 7

3 3 4 6 9 9 9
2 2 4 6 7 7 7
    ^ ^
```

There are two solutions.

Actually, two scans are enough.

Comment: I don't get the third step. Can you please elaborate it?

Comment: @MaxZuber: your comment doesn't belong here.

Comment: @RaghavendraRagha: 4 <= 4 and 6 <= 6.

Comment: This is something new, loved the way you did .

Answer (score 1):

This is an O(3n) = O(n) implementation:

```
private static int findPivot(int[] a) {
    int length = a.length;
    int[] leftMax = new int[length];
    int[] rightMin = new int[length];
    leftMax[0] = a[0];
    for(int i=1; i<length; i++) {
        leftMax[i] = leftMax[i-1]>a[i]?leftMax[i-1]:a[i];  
    }

    rightMin[length -1] = a[length-1];
    for(int i=length-2; i>0; i--) {
        rightMin[i] = rightMin[i+1]<a[i]?rightMin[i+1]:a[i];  
    }

    int position = -1;
    for(int i=1; i<length-1; i++) {
        if(leftMax[i-1] < rightMin[i+1]) {
            position = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    return position;
}
```

These are the running results:

```
Initial array:  [5, -1, 3, 8, 6, 10]
Partitions:     [5, -1] 3 [8, 6, 10]
Initial array:  [5, 5, -2, -3, 0, 3, 8, 6, 10]
Partitions:     [5, 5, -2, -3, 0] 3 [8, 6, 10]
Initial array:  [3, -2, -2, -3, 0, 7, 2, 8, 6, 10]
Partitions:     [3, -2, -2, -3, 0, 7, 2, 8] 6 [10]
```

And here is how to print it that way:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] a = { 5, -1, 3, 8, 6, 10 };

    int pivot = findPivot(a);
    if (pivot != -1) {
        printPartitions(pivot, a);
    }
    int[] b = { 5, 5, -2, -3, 0, 3, 8, 6, 10 };
    int pivot1 = findPivot(b);
    if (pivot1 != -1) {
        printPartitions(pivot1, b);
    }
    int[] c = { 3, -2, -2, -3, 0, 7, 2, 8, 6, 10 };
    int pivot2 = findPivot(c);
    if (pivot2 != -1) {
        printPartitions(pivot2, c);
    }
}

private static void printPartitions(int pivot, int[] a) {
    System.out.println("Initial array:\t" + Arrays.toString(a));
    System.out.println("Partitions:\t" + Arrays.toString(Arrays.copyOfRange(a, 0, pivot)) + " " + a[pivot] + " "
            + Arrays.toString(Arrays.copyOfRange(a, pivot + 1, a.length)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// example with n2 complexity. 

class Elementwithleftsidesmallerandrightsidegreater {

  static void find(int[] arr) {

    for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {

        int head = arr[i];

        int left = i - 1;
        int right = i + 1;

        while (left >= 0 && arr[left] < head) {

            left--;
        }

        while (right < arr.length && arr[right] > head) {
            right++;
        }

        if (left == -1 && right == arr.length) {
            System.out.println("index is " + i);
            System.out.println("value is " + arr[i]);

        }

    }

  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int arr[] = new int[] { 2, 1, 1, 3, 111, 80, 100, 79, 19 };

    find(arr);

  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It's O(n):

I've replaced my algorithm description with a code on JavaScript, so you can simply run it and see what's going on there. This code can be easily converted to C++.

```js
var arrayItems = [1, 3, 2, 3, 4, 6, 4, 7, 9, 10, 8];
var sizeOfArray = arrayItems.length;
var maxValue = arrayItems[0];
var pointValue = maxValue;
var elIndex = -1;
for (var index = 0; index < sizeOfArray; index++) {
  var set = false;

  // Check set of new point value
  if (-1 === elIndex && arrayItems[index] > maxValue) {
    pointValue = arrayItems[index];
    elIndex = index;
    set = true;
  }

  // Update max value
  if (arrayItems[index] > maxValue) {
    maxValue = arrayItems[index];
  }

  // Reset point value
  if (!set && -1 !== elIndex && arrayItems[index] <= pointValue) {
    pointValue = maxValue;
    elIndex = -1;
  }

  console.log([arrayItems[index], maxValue, pointValue, elIndex, index]);
}

console.log(elIndex);
```

When to the loop ends you'll get the value in `elIndex`:

---

```
 arrayItems:  1  3  2  3  4  6  4  7  9  10   8
   maxValue:  1  3  3  3  4  6  6  7  9  10  10
 pointValue:  1  3  3  3  4  4  6  7  7   7   7
    elIndex: -1  1 -1 -1  4  4 -1  7  7   7   7
      index:  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8   9  10
```

Comment: It works fine for [3, 2, 4, 6, 9, 8, 7], returning index 2, which stands for "4". What is your example?

Comment: Sorry, failing on my first example as should.